# Installed npm but command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I'm installing the following package on Linux Mint

https://github.com/frida/frida-compile

I try to install it by

```
~ $ sudo npm install frida-compile
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/david/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/david/package.json'
npm WARN david No description
npm WARN david No repository field.
npm WARN david No README data
npm WARN david No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ frida-compile@5.3.7
updated 1 package in 2.883s
[!] 2 vulnerabilities found [21344 packages audited]
    Severity: 2 Low
    Run `npm audit` for more detail
```

And when I run `frida-compile` on the command line, I get

```
frida-compile: command not found
```

Any idea what the issue is here?

I am running Node 8.11.1

Comment: It doesn't look like you installed the package globally (`-g`).  Try using `npx frida-compile`.

Comment: sudo npm install `-g` frida-compile